# IDE HDD not showing up after installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, sata

Okay, so that title is really messy and non-linear, as least to me, and that's because I don't know how to properly title it, but I can describe it.

**Essentially** I have 3 hard drives in my machine. They were all working fine and appearing on Windows.

Yesterday, I formatted one of those drives to have **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it.** To ensure that I didn't mess anything up with the other drives, I disconnected them from my machine. After installing Ubuntu, I came back onto Windows to see if it still saw my second hard drive (as I know it won't see the other hard drive since its got Ubuntu on it)... It didn't see my hard drive **---** I've been in **Disk Management** as well and it only sees Local Disk (C) and a System Reserved partition.

My hard drives are as follows; **1 SSD - 500GIG**, **1 HDD - 320GIG [IDE]**, **1 HDD - 400GIG(?) [SATA/ATA]**

When I go into my BIOS, it sees the hard drive with Ubuntu on it, which is the **SATA/ATA** but does not see the **IDE** one and where **IDE Primary Drive** is, it just says undetected.

How can I get my machine to detect this hard drive... Everything was working fine before I put Ubuntu on one of my hard drive - not to blame it.. (IRONY).

***PS: I have it as "SATA/ATA" as I'm not sure which one it actually is.. It connects through SATA but I believe I've seen Speccy classify it as ATA.***

Comment: `as I know it won't see the other hard drive since its got Ubuntu on it` You should see all drives in Disk Management anyway.

Comment: "IDE" (PATA) drives have that master/slave nuisance. You have to connect the drive to the port on the cable that matches with the jumper setting on the drive. I suppose if the master port doesn't work, it should then work with the slave port, or vice versa, though. http://www.betaarchive.com/imageupload/1304159566.or.33063.gif

Comment: What if you don't have the little piece that you are supposed to use to indicate whether it's a master/slave? I don't have that piece and it has worked just fine for me - up until Ubuntu, that is.

Comment: Well I faintly remember that there were some PATA disks that came out in the later days do not have jumper setting but instead can adapt automatically.

Comment: I found the piece to select what the drive is MASTER/SLAVE/ETC and it still didn't do anything.